# Cannot use custom LightningElement in Custom Tab (Settings page) - Error in the server action response

Tags: lightning-web-components, flexipages

Cannot render lwc component for settings page in my app,
It's [sample Lightning element](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/projects/quick-start-lightning-web-components/create-a-hello-world-lightning-web-component) and it works fine with my widget,
but i cannot add any LWC on my settings page (custom tab/flexipage).

I got this when enable debug mode:
Error in the server action response:An internal server error has occurred
Error ID: 1856001359-49942 (1726703216)

Custom tab

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CustomTab xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <description>Settings</description>
    <flexiPage>Settings</flexiPage>
    <label>Settings</label>
    <mobileReady>true</mobileReady>
    <motif>Custom46: Postage</motif>
</CustomTab>
```

Flexipage

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<FlexiPage xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <flexiPageRegions>
        <name>center</name>
        <type>Region</type>
    </flexiPageRegions>
    <type>AppPage</type>
    <masterLabel>Settings</masterLabel>
    <template>
        <name>MySettings</name>
    </template>
</FlexiPage>
```

Design

```
<design:component label="">
    <flexipage:template>
        <flexipage:region name="center" defaultWidth="LARGE" />
    </flexipage:template>
</design:component>
```

Component

```
<aura:component implements="lightning:appHomeTemplate" access="global">
    <aura:attribute name="center" type="Aura.Component[]" access="global"/>
    <c:mySample />
</aura:component>
```

Comment: There's no way we'd know what's going on without seeing some code. Can you please [edit] your quesion to include some code. Please read about [ask] so you can provide the information we look for so we can help you.

Comment: I got it! I had to put {!v.center} in component and setup page via <componentInstances> in flexipage.